# Stop a textarea acting as a drag target for images

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, textarea

I have various elements on the page that can be dragged onto various drop zones. However for the textarea I can't find a way to show to the user that a draggable image suitable for a different zone, may not be dropped in the textarea.

I tried all kinds of combinations handling the ondragenter and ondragover events but it has been impossible to show the "no drop" icon when the image is dragged over the textarea.

There are lots of tutorials and tips on how to made a drop zone accept everything. I want to know how to make a dropzone and a textarea in particular reject a drag item. Turning of drag behavior for the item is not an option because there are other zones that should accept that image.

This JS fiddle shows that by default an image can be dragged into a textarea resulting in the URL being shown. I would love some help showing me how to stop that.

```
function dragstart(event) {//stuff}

function dragenter(event) {event.preventDefault();}

function dragover(event) {event.preventDefault();}

function dragdrop(event) {event.preventDefault();}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mWKd3/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You aren't binding/attaching your events**, for the attributes ***ondragstart, ondragenter, ondragover,*** and ***ondragdrop*** are not defined.

Here is a new fiddle that displays it http://jsfiddle.net/mWKd3/18/

## **In-Short - the Javascript (I'm using jQuery to attach the events)**

```
$("img").bind("dragstart",function(e){
});

$("textarea").bind("dragenter",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("textarea").bind("dragover",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("textarea").bind("dragdrop",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The following was an alternative method of doing drag-n-drop.

Referencing http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/ and extending your jsfiddle

## **HTML***

```
<div style='height:2em;display:block;'></div>
<img id='imgarea'  src="http://www.planetinaction.com/images/gexplorer_logo48.png" draggable="true">
<textarea id='tarea' class="textzone"></textarea>
    <div id='debugger' style='top:0em;left:5em;right:0em;height:2em;width:auto;position:absolute;display:block;'>Debug Window</div>
```

## **CSS***

```
.targetzone {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.textzone {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

## ***Javascript****

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.dragstart = function(opt) {

        opt = $.extend({handle:"",cursor:"move"}, opt);

        if(opt.handle === "") {
            var $el = this;
        } else {
            var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
        }
        return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function(e) {
            if(opt.handle === "") {
                var $drag = $(this).addClass('draggable');
            } else {
                var $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
            }
            var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
                drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
                drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
                pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
                pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;          
        $(this).data("start_pos_x",$drag.offset().left);
        $(this).data("start_pos_y",$drag.offset().top);
        $(this).data("start_z_idx",z_idx);
            $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove", function(e) {
                $('.draggable').offset({
                    top:e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                    left:e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
                });

            }).on("mouseup", function(e) {
                    $(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
                  $("#debugger").append(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX,e.pageY).id + " was selected!");
            })
            e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
        }).on("mouseup", function() {
            if(opt.handle === "") {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
            }
        $(this).offset({
            top: $(this).data("start_pos_y"),
            left: $(this).data("start_pos_x")
        });
    });

    }
})(jQuery);

$("img").dragstart();
```